# How do loop through a dynamic SQL statement using a cursor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the code below. When i run it i get the same value for all the rows fetched by the cursor. I want it to display the result fetched by the dynamic SQL and if the value returned is null i want the code to display 'N'. Please help.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DIM_MASTER] AS


DECLARE

@V_DIM VARCHAR(80),
@V_STMT nVARCHAR(max),
@result varchar(10),
@res varchar(10),
@CURSOR_DIM cursor


set @CURSOR_DIM = CURSOR 
 FOR 
 SELECT FieldName FROM desc_user.dim_master

open @CURSOR_DIM

fetch next from @CURSOR_DIM into @V_DIM

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

set @V_STMT = 
'select  @res = '+'''Y''' +' 
        where exists(select * from [desc_user].[ticket_master] 
        where @v_dim is not null)'  


 EXECUTE sp_executesql @V_STMT, N'@v_dim varchar(80),@res varchar(10)         OUTPUT',@v_dim = @v_dim,@res = @resULT OUTPUT
print @v_stmt


select @res as result

UPDATE desc_user.Dimension_Details set FieldValue = @res
where FieldName = @V_DIM


FETCH NEXT FROM @CURSOR_DIM
                INTO @V_DIM
                END

                CLOSE @CURSOR_DIM
                DEALLOCATE @CURSOR_DIM
```

Comment: Why is that query dynamic in the first place?

Comment: @andriy : bcz we are creating a .net application and we need to test by passing variables to this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your dynamic query never produces a null. When the condition in the dynamic query's WHERE clause is met, the output parameter is assigned a `Y`. But when the condition is not met, nothing happens, and the `@res` parameter keeps the value assigned at the `sp_executesql` line – consequently, the `@result` variable keeps its previous value too.

In order to produce a null, you need to change the structure of the dynamic query. Instead of this:

```
SELECT @var = … WHERE …
```

make it this:

```
SET @var = (SELECT … WHERE …)
```

That way, when the condition is not met, the SELECT will return nothing, which will be interpreted as a scalar null and assigned to the `@var` accordingly. You can then turn your null into `N` or anything else as necessary. You can, of course, do that immediately in the dynamic query if that is the only way you want to treat those nulls:

```
SET @res = ISNULL((SELECT 'Y' WHERE …), 'N');
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to create a GLOBAL temporary table (double hash) that has the columns defined to receive the results from your dynamic SQL statement.  Then modify your dynamic SQL statement to INSERT INTO ##GlobalTable SELECT ... from your dynamic sql statement.  After the execution of your dynamic SQL statement, your GLOBAL temporary table will have the results and you can query that in the main SP.  You'd need to truncate the GLOBAL temporary table before each dynamic SQL call